# How to verify performance of designed Kalman Filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

In the literature I have come across two ways how to verify performance of a Kalman filter.

(a) During the run of Kalman filter you keep information about *innovation* 
[image] in every step [image], where [image] is the observed output of the system and [image] is the predicted output in the same step. Then you take the autocovariance of the *innovation* and according to whether the function exceeds or doesn't exceeed certain bounds, you can conclude something about the performance of your Kalman Filter.

But that's where the explanation ends. How do I decide what bounds it shouldn't exceed and what does it say about the Kalman filter design?

(b) Aside of *innovation* you also keep track of *innovation covariance matrix* [image] and in each step you compute *trust region* [image]. And again, there is supposed to be a bound over which the function shouldn't grow. But this is where the explanation ends and I'm left without the knowledge of how to determine the bound and what does it say about my Kalman filter.

Comment: It sounds interesting. Could you provide a link to the mentioned literature, so I can try to help you?

Comment: @Anton I was interested in this question because of the homework. I have learned how to evaluate Kalman filter performance, because I had to put it in my report. There is a link to my report: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xwjspkymjgfx  The performance evaluation is described in section 5.

Comment: @Anton I have found one pdf file of the used literature. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ucj6F4m_bDhNcCFqNy49AjpdvqsvV7zG